# Spring, Hikari and multiple DB schemas

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, hikaricp

I have a web app that can connect to multiple DB instances and multiple schemas on each instance (there is one schema per tenant). I use [AbstractRoutingDataSource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/lookup/AbstractRoutingDataSource.html) to manage a [HikariDataSource](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.zaxxer/HikariCP/3.2.0/com/zaxxer/hikari/HikariDataSource.html) for each instance. When a request comes in I need to get the dataSource and use `setCatalog(tenantId)` to set the schema. The problem is, the subsequent query fails with `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'my_previous_schema.my_table' doesn't exist`. Where `my_previous_schema` is the schema set for the dataSource before I called `setCatalog`.

I suspect what's happening is that the PreparedStatement created by the JPARepository used `my_previous_schema`, but I'm not 100% sure. Any ideas on how to resolve this?